# Acceso a RowCommand aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

Tengo una tabla de uno a uno de radicaciones a documentos adjuntos, cuando creo un radicado, debo adjuntarle un archivo.

Tengo estos controles:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Archivo" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fu1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnguardar" runat="server" Text="Adjuntar" CommandName="up" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Funcionalidad del botón:

```
protected void gvradica_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Button btnUp = e.CommandSource as Button;
    if (e.CommandName.ToLower() != "up")
    {
        return;
    }

    FileUpload fu = btnUp.FindControl("fu1") as FileUpload;
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
        DOCADJUNTO da = new DOCADJUNTO();
        if (fu.HasFile)
        {
            da.ID_RADICACION_FK = 1; // El numero 1 es un dato quemado
            da.NOMBRE = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fu.PostedFile.FileName);
            da.EXTENSION = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fu.PostedFile.FileName);
            da.ARCHIVO = fu.FileBytes;
            adoDocAdj.agregarAdjunto(da);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que se quiere es que el `ID_RADICACIÓN_FK` lo traiga de manera automática, de la fila de la grilla seleccionada, pero no he podido hacerlo, lo he intentado hacerlo de las siguientes formas.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
da.ID_RADICACION_FK = Convert.ToInt32(gvradica.DataKeys[index].Value);

GridViewRow row = gvradica.SelectedRow;
da.ID_RADICACION_FK = Convert.ToInt32(gvradica.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

GridViewRow row = gvradica.SelectedRow;
da.ID_RADICACION_FK=Convert.ToInt32(gvradica.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["ID_RADICACION"]);

var query = from ra in contexto.RADICACIONES select new { ra.ID_RADICACION };

da.ID_RADICACION_FK = int.Parse(gvradica.SelectedDataKey.Values[0].ToString() + "" + gvradica.SelectedDataKey.Values[1].ToString());

da.ID_RADICACION_FK = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Ninguna sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder utilizar `e.CommandArgument`, primero debes asignarle un valor único a cada botón, en este caso el id de la fila:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnguardar" runat="server" Text="Adjuntar" CommandName="up" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
```

Luego ya puedes capturarlo en el evento RowCommand:

```
da.ID_RADICACION_FK = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Comment: Persiste el error, aparece esto ahora

Comment: Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK_DOCADJUNTO_RADICACIONES". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "gc1", tabla "dbo.RADICACIONES", column 'ID_RADICACION'.
Se terminó la instrucción.

Comment: Eso es un problema a nivel de la base de datos con tu llave foránea. Para poder ayudarte, lo mejor sería que crees una nueva pregunta, indicando además la estructura de las tablas, la data que tengan y con que datos falla el insert.